# Installing Unity alongside KDE

Tags: unity, kubuntu, kde

I have been running Kubuntu 15.10 32-bit for a while, and although I love the KDE enviroment, I would like the option of having Unity. So, I did the following:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install unity
```

I then rebooted, and when I was at the login screen, I tried to switch from plasma to unity, but the only options were "Plasma" and "Failsafe". When i run:

```
sudo apt list | grep gnome
```

or:

```
sudo apt list | grep unity
```

I am presented with several packages saying "Unity-8-desktop", or something along those lines, so I know Unity is installed, I just can't reach it. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want Unity 7:

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop
```

If you want Unity 8:

```
sudo apt install unity8-desktop-session-mir
```

Comment: I tried that, but it still doesn't show up in the login screen

Comment: Run sudo dpkg-reconfigure kdm, choose lightdm when asked, and reboot your PC.

Comment: I did that, but the output was the following 'dpkg-query: package 'kdm' is not installed and no information is available   Use dpkg --info(= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files,    and dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list their contents.    /usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure: kdm is not installed'

Comment: I tried again, but i figured you must have meant 'dpkg-reconfigure sddm' and not 'dpkg-reconfigure kdm'. When I did that, it worked. However, both sddm and lightdm started fighting on the login screen. I then ran 'systemctl disable sddm', rebooted, and it's working fine now.